# Return query based on Months selected

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a SQL statement to `SELECT` all records with specific months checked. I have a form that has checkboxes for January to December, depending on which of the checkboxes are checked it will do a SQL query to return the rows of the selected months.

I cannot think of a `WHERE` condition to get this to work, I can only think of doing 78 different queries with `IF` conditions of `WHERE MONTH(happened_at) = 1 AND MONTH(happened_at) = 3`and so on until all available options are covered.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Tag your question with the database you are actually using.  And, where do you get "78"?

Comment: I thought that was the different number of available combinations, I may be wrong with my math, now that i think about it it should be 12! which is over 400 million.

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try
`SELECT ... WHERE MONTH(happened_at) IN (1,2,4,7)`

Best is, you make yourself familiar with VBA and code an according function like so:

```
Private Function CreateSQL
 Dim str As String
 str = IIf(Me.cbJan, ",1", "") & _
       IIf(Me.cbFeb, ",2", "") & _
       IIf(Me.cbAug, ",8", "")
  str = Mid(str, 2)
  CreateSQL = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE MONTH(happened_at) IN (" & str & ");"
End Sub
```

That is: You create the month-list inside the brackets by adding a comma and that months number, then you copy everything except that first comma and put it in the brackets...

Comment: Wouldn't I still need 78 different queries then? Because I would need to cover every option, `IN (1,2), IN (2,3,7), IN (3,6,11)`

Comment: Could you clarify your question with examples ?

Comment: So I have a form with months (checkboxes), depending on what is checked say January,March,June,August. The SQL query should return something like `SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE MONTH(happened_at) IN (1,3,6,8)`. The user can select any combination of months.

Comment: I tried `IIF(Forms!Switchboard!January=True,'1','')` and `IIF(Forms!Switchboard!January,'1','')` both return false for some reason, any idea why?

Comment: Worked like a charm, I found out the reason I was pulling my hair out is because I was naming the textbox beside the checkbox and referencing that instead of the actual checkbox when writing my `Sub`, which took over 3 hours to figure out. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try a [WHILE loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms178642.aspx) perhaps.

```
-- Declare your month.
DECLARE @MONTH_NUM INT = 1
-- Establish your table.
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE
(
    MONTH_NUM INT, 
    COL1 VARCHAR(255),
    COL2 VARCHAR(255)
)
-- Set the WHILE loop cap.
WHILE @MONTH_NUM <= 78
-- Begin your loop.
BEGIN
    -- Insert your values into the table.
    INSERT INTO @TABLE (MONTH_NUM, COL1, COL2)
    SELECT
        T.MONTH_NUM
        ,T.COL1
        ,T.COL2
    FROM [TABLE] T
        WHERE @MONTH_NUM = T.MONTH_NUM
    -- Set the month counter.
    SET @MONTH_NUM = @MONTH_NUM + 1
END
-- Return your results.
SELECT
    T.MONTH_NUM
    ,T.COL1
    ,T.COL2
FROM
    @TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Prepare 12 variables for the checkboxes.  Then assign them numeric values:

```
if <checkbox1 is checked> then $box01 = 1 else $box01 = 0;  -- or NULL
if <checkbox2 is checked> then $box02 = 2 else $box01 = 0;
. . .
```

Then construct the query to do:

```
where month(happened_at) in ($box01, $box02, $box03, . . . , $box12)
```

Then, ponder why you don't just have a `start_month` and `end_month`.

Comment: Im trying to do this in VBA and when i try and do `If Forms!Switchboard!May = True Then`. I get an "Object doesn't support this property or method" error, I've tried everything but it wont work